# Keyboard-key and the resulting character. Who is responsible (in the OS)

Tags: operating-system, key, character

Pressing a key on the keyboard results in different types of characters in different OS's.
e.g. pressing the up arrow in windows will result in another sequence of characters then pressing the same key in linux.

So the question is: Which "part" of an OS is responsible?
Especially when looking at GNU\linux OS's since "linux" is only the kernel.

Comment: This question seems better suited at [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @cad is there a way to "move" this question?

Comment: I think it is user level (shell) part of system as for linux and depends on used encoding (special arrays that converts codes from keyboard to signs).

Comment: Do you remember when you install os one option is to select keyboard format . At that time OS maps keyboard to different codes.  So different OS use different mapping then it is possible to have different result